# How much do grades from beginning of bachelors impact PhD admission?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, grades

Do low grades in standard 12 and first year of bachelors (including a few repeats) hamper the admission to a PhD course in Europe if one has a research paper published and a masters degree in relevant discipline with decent grades?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does a bad grade in one course (with otherwise OK record) affect graduate admissions?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/28409/does-a-bad-grade-in-one-course-with-otherwise-ok-record-affect-graduate-admiss)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may depend on the country as well as university/institute. You should have a look at the corresponding websites, as most information regarding PhD admission can be found online.

For example, the TU Munich website [1] states:

> Results are considered to be above average if studies were completed
>   with an average grade of at least 2.5, or at a minimum passed with a
>   grade of “good.” In exceptional cases, your above-average
>   qualifications can also be proven through academic work (e.g.
>   publications) completed after your course of study.

This means that your bachelor or earlier grades to not affect PhD admission as a hard citerion. However, when you hand in your application the professor will have a look at ALL your grades. It is his/her finial decision whether to accept you, so all your grades might have an influence on the outcome.

Personally, I have experienced that having publications beforehand helps a lot. Thereby you prove that you have at least a basic understanding of scientific work. This may give you an advantage compared to other applicants.

[1] https://www.gs.tum.de/en/applicants/application/requirements/