# Do graduate school admissions look at first grade of a repeated course in the undergraduate transcript?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, computer-science

I wanted to know if graduate school admissions committees(specifically for Computer Science) look at all the grades for a repeated course (re-taken once after freshman year) even though all grades except the last one isn't valid anymore as it isn't included in the GPA.

On the same note, is improvement between grades of a course valued more than a bad grade gotten in the first place?

Comment: The graduate admissions committee consists of people.  Some of those people will actually look at your transcript.  Some of _those_ people will see your grades from freshman year.  And only some of _those_ people will notice that you took the same course again later.

Comment: Related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/28409/19607 http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/71107/19607

Comment: Should this question be closed?