# 3.65 GPA, 1 D on Undergraduate Transcript; MBA in Top 10

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, business-school

Looking to apply to a top 10 MBA program in a few years.

Currently finishing up my undergraduate degree at a top 20 national university. I have a 3.65 GPA, majoring in Computer Science, and have a Business Concentration.

I got 1 D in my second semester of freshmen year in a basic CS class (Algorithms). I've done significantly better in all of my classes with a range of A+ to B across the board. The semester I received a D in one class, I took too many hours and couldn't do well on all my exams. That semester, it was that one class that I got a D in - otherwise I had all As and A+s.

I'm hoping to work in industry for a few years before applying to MBA school but would love to learn what the **serious** chances/challenges/implications are as I apply to a Top 10 MBA School. I just want to get a better trajectory on where my career path lies.

*The dream is to be in technology management - a CTO, VP of Engineering etc.*

Comment: ...which is a duplicate of [Will one 'C' grade due to health issues ruin my chances of admission into a top grad school?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/10621/65)