# Effect of Master's grades on PhD application to top unis in Europe

Tags: phd, europe, grades

I am a master's student in stem cell biology at one of the TUs in Germany. It's been one year of my program and my current grade average is 2.2 GPA almost equivalent to 75-80%. The thing is I am planning to apply to very competitive universities for PhD, such as ETH Zürich, TUM, etc. I am doing my best to gain more experience in the field I plan to work in my Ph.D. and even have good grades (1.0) (96-100%) in the subjects I like and want to pursue further. I want to know how much the grades matter overall for such competitive places. If I have enough motivation and experience in the field would it help to overlook the grade? What should I expect in terms of response from PIs in those universities?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will one 'C' grade due to health issues ruin my chances of admission into a top grad school?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10621/will-one-c-grade-due-to-health-issues-ruin-my-chances-of-admission-into-a-top)

Comment: @user438383 OP asked specifically about Europe, which has a different culture in this respect than, say, the US. For example, recommendation letters may play a much smaller role.

Comment: Also relevant https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38237/how-are-ph-d-applications-evaluated-in-the-us-particularly-for-weak-or-borderl

Comment: and https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/176908/how-does-the-admissions-process-work-for-ph-d-programs-in-country-x

Comment: Applying the concept of "top universities" across different European countries is rather misleading, as the following sentence nicely demonstrates: *"apply to very competitive universities for PhD, such as [...] TUM"*. That's not how things work in Germany; to do a PhD at TU Munich you need to find an advisor there and you need to find funding. For both points it's mostly irrelevant how "competitive" (whatever this means) the university is. It completely depends on the individual professor there with whom you'd like to do your PhD.

Comment: But admittedly, the marketing team of TU Munich did a [great job](https://www.gs.tum.de/en/gs/applicants/application/) in making it appear as if they had some kind of "graduate program" to which you have to "apply", similarly to how things work in, say, the US. But when reading the details one sees that there is no "application" process to become a PhD student at all, but that things work the same way as everywhere in Germany. (But this kind of marketing stunt seems to be a specialty of TU Munich; they do something similar for their Bachelor's degree in math.)

Answer (score 1):

I think that from an european perspective it is quite unimpressive (and even counter-productive) to focus so much on the unis being "top" unis.

To be considered for a PhD you have to show determination (like having good grades in the relevant subjects), to show capabilities (like having good grades in the fundamental subjects) and to know your inner motivations for a PhD.

Universities are not a conveyor belt to success, not even the top unis.  Universities are just a toolbox to let you research what you want to research. Apply to the universities providing you good infrastructures and sufficient funds to travel to conference/workshops. Rankings and "perceived" top unis are just a picture of the past, focusing on them you may miss good opportunities from other universities that will be top unis in the 4 years of your PhD.

If you get into a PhD program by a "top uni" without an extremely strong personal motivation on the reasons that brought you there and how the top uni can contribute to your research, it is likely you will be psychologically squashed by all the bullshit and marketing crap coming from the pressure of the "top" status of the uni and nothing more.

Comment: Ignoring all ranking and marketing wishwash: As far as doctoral studies are concerned, working in a "top uni" in a specific field has tangible differences from an average university. This is mostly because the people you work and interact with during your PhD influence your approach to research and thus, your career perspectives.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper that is your opinion, my european opinion is that if you are good enough to work and interact with people relevant to your research while at a top uni, you are good enough to work and interact with people relevant to your *future career* at an average university (local companies, other experts in the field). Top universities have a huge advantage at later career stage, when you need funds to start your own research group and similar. At the phd level, succes is still mostly in the hand of the phd (and possibly  its background).